# SimpleXML Element 'x' is already used with 'x'

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I am trying to deal with some XML that redefines itself as a child.  By this I mean I have the following XML fragment:

```
<ns4:Warning>
    <ns4:Symptom DTCList="2~3~600E18~C2797~NONE" sortOrder="5460">
        <ns4:Symptom>Symptom description ...</ns4:Symptom>
    </ns4:Symptom>
</<ns4:Warning>
```

I am receiving the following error from SimpleXML:

```
Element 'Symptom' is already used with @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(name=Symptom, data=false, type=void, required=false) on field 'symptom' com.foo.response.xml.SymptomNS4 com.foo.response.xml.Warning.symptom at line 1
```

Warning class:

```
@Root(name = "Warning")
public class Warning {
    @Element(name = "Symptom") SymptomNS4 symptom;
}
```

SymptomNS4 class:

```
@Root(name = "Symptom")
public class SymptomNS4 {
    @Attribute(name = "DTCList") String dtcList;
    @Attribute(name = "sortOrder") String sortOrder;
    @Element(name = "Symptom") String symptom;
}
```

Obviously, the approach I took is not working. How do you model this chunk of XML in SimpleXML?

Comment: Are you using a current version of simple? If have tested the classes with serialization and they work. Btw. they are missing the `@Namespace` and there's a typo in your xml (`</<ns4:Warning>`).

Comment: Yes, I am using Simple XML 2.7.1 which is the latest shown on the Maven central repository.  The reason you don't see the @Namespace here is that it is defined farther up at a higher level because of other elements that use the ns4 namespace.

Comment: Are you testing serialization or deserialization?

Comment: Deserialization, taking an XML document and breaking it down into Java objects.

Comment: Ok, you can go the opposite direction for testing: Take an object, serialize it and check if the result is valid. So at least your annotations are ok.